# Should we merge [car] and [cars]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

- [car](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car) has 6 questions and no description.
- [cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) has 32 questions and a description.

Should we merge these two?

Comment: FYI: the car tag is now merged into cars (car is no longer used by any question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I think we should merge the two tags because they appear to be used for the same kind of questions, but the final decision is up to the community. Everyone with [1250 or more reputation](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) can [suggest tag synonyms](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and/or approve suggestions. If we want to merge the two then we need to decide what the main tag will be; cars or car. Either is fine by me. We don't seem to be consistent with singular or plural when it comes to tags (for example [batteries](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries), [building-materials](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building-materials), [electric-vehicles](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicles) but also [vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle), [plastic](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastic), [green-roof](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-roof)), although I think plural is a bit more common than singular.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten how to do that. I suggested the synonym [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested).